# How to make a walk cycle loop?

Tags: animation, modifiers, graph-editor, nla-editor, dopesheet

I've made a walk cycle that I would like to repeat a certain number of times. When I tried to "Make Cyclical" the entire armature animation I realized that the Graph Editor's modifiers only appear to work on an individual bone basis. Is it necessary to make and manage separate cyclical modifiers for each bone, or is there a better way? Thanks.

[image: Cyclical bone animation]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the walk cycle is the only thing you want in your animation, you could just make the timeline the same length as the walk cycle. It'll loop automatically.

Otherwise, if the walk cycle is in your timeline, you can go to the NLA editor with the rig selected (in object mode), and click on the double-down-arrow icon, which will save the walk cycle as an action.

[image: Defining the walk cycle as an action in the NLA editor]

Then you can use the N key properties window to change the amount of times the action is repeated.

[image: Specifying how many times the walk cycle should repeat]

This is, IMHO, the best solution as it gives you more flexibility to work with animations.

Comment: Thanks, this is the info I needed! I added some images to your answer to make it more clear for other readers.